# Capturing videos with Cordova (PhoneGap) in half screen.

Tags: ios, cordova, video, cordova-plugins

I'm building a Cordova app with a video capturing feature. Focusing on iOS devices. I'm currently using the **videoCapture** plugin. I would like the ability to set the size of the capturing screen to just half the screen (to be able to show content on the phones screen at the same time as the video is captured).

I have been looking in to some Cordova plugins such as [SnapsCamera](https://github.com/SnapsApp/snaps_camera) and it seems to do sort of what I need but it lacks documentation and dosen't look well supported.

*Any recommendations about other plugins or ways to go from here?*

---

(My knowledge in objective C /Swift is very limited)